# SVN authorization failure, trunk non-existent in head revision, getting a GIT repository working in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, svn, egit

To simplify things, I have one local SVN repository `D:\folder\repo_name` and I have svnserve running as a service with root set to the mentioned path. Subclipse and SmartSVN can connect to the repository, also displays the correct head revision number, but when I try to explore the trunk (the only branch) it gives the following error: `URL 'svn://localhost/trunk' non-existent in that revision`. This while I can check out the complete repository perfectly fine. But I don't need the all the branches, I need just the contents of the trunk.

When I try to commit I get the error `Authentication failed`. However my credentials were fine when checking out earlier.

When I try to get my stuff out of there and move to GIT (which I suppose would be best as everything is always kept local), the `git svn clone` process completes, I see all my revisions and files pass in GIT Bash, and then try to import it in Eclipse. I see that it tries to import the project into the repository directory itself (see http://wiki.eclipse.org/Image:Egit-0.9-import-projects-general-project.png). Needless to say I get the error in the shape of `D:\folder\repo_name_git overlaps the location of another project: 'repo_name_git'` What I don't get is why I can't seem to find a single way to let me specify where I want the project to import into.

Alternatively, when I add the project in the git repository as an existing project into Eclipse, and then - through the Team > Share menu - try to get under version control, I get the error `Can not move project to target location D:\folder\repo_name_git, as this location overlaps with location D:\folder\repo_name_git, which contains a .project file`

I'm at a loss and these errors are to generic to give me an idea of how to tackle them. Any heads up would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

2 points:

1. I was getting "Authentication failed" on "correct" credentials - except the plugin I used was forcing the first letter of my username to uppercase - check the case of your username (upper or lower).
2. I've just had a problem moving onto a Subversion 1.7 repository, which is not supported by my Subversive plugin, and I was getting some strange errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the credentials

1. make sure svnserve is not started with -R {readonly option}
2. Check if the following lines are commented in 
   "\REPO_NAME\conf\svnserve.conf
   anon-access = read
   auth-access = write
   password-db = passwd"